# Is it always true that the complement of an ample divisor is affine?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, divisors, ample-bundles

Consider a proper and integral scheme $X\rightarrow\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ over a Noetherian ring $A$ and $D\in\operatorname{Div}(X)$ an effective ample Cartier divisor on $X$. Is it true that its complement $X\setminus\operatorname{Supp}(D)$ is affine? If not, then what would be the necessary conditions on $A$ that would make it true?

If $A$ is an algebraically closed field, then this is a classical result, whose proof can be found (for example) here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264131/is-the-complement-of-an-ample-divisor-always-affine

and some relevant stuff is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1197197/relationship-between-very-ample-divisors-and-hyperplane-sections and here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2450746/a-definition-of-a-very-ample-divisor.

Even with the ideas from these links, I can't really solve the problem. I mostly tried using the property that a very ample divisor induces a closed embedding, but I suspect my arguments might be too elementary.
I would be interested, in particular, in the case where $A$ is a Dedekind ring (or, if not, a DVR).

Comment: I think this follows more or less as in your first link from https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01VU -- some power of $\mathscr{O}(D)$ is relatively very ample, and then one can imitate the given proof.